# Send number via netcat

Tags: matlab, unix, udp, netcat

I want to send a single number via netcat. I don't want to send the ASCII representation of the number, but the binary version of the number (uint8, int32, etc.). I have a UDP port open in Matlab that is waiting to receive the number. Matlab's [dsp.UDPReceiver](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.udpreceiver-system-object.html) can only accept ['uint8' (default) | 'double' | 'single' | 'int8' | 'int16' | 'uint16' | 'int32' | 'uint32' | 'logical']. FYI, I am sending integers via UDP to a process to control some action therein.

I originally tried

```
echo 5 | netcat -u localhost 12345
```

but the receiver (in Matlab) prints out `ans =  uint8   53` because the output of `echo` is the string not the binary representation of the number 5. I tried using `bc` like this:

```
echo "obase=2;5" | bc -l|netcat -u localhost 12345
```

but get the result `ans = uint8   49` because `bc` is returning the ASCII version of the binary rather than the bits themselves.

How can I send a single number via netcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the option `-e` echo supports given the bytes as hexadecimal or octal. With `-n` the final newline gets supressed:

```
echo -n -e '\x05' | netcat ...
```

Comment: Bingo. This works perfectly.  Thanks.